# Construction an if statement with else Python

Tags: python, if-statement, structure

I have an if statement in python like so

```
if number == 1 and letter == a:
    print 'Correct'
else:
    print 'Incorrect'
if number == 2 and letter == b:
    print 'Correct'
else:
    print 'Incorrect'
```

But it doesn't work.. How do you construct something like this?

Answer (score 3):

the construction of your if statement is alright. the problem is that

```
letter == a
```

and

```
letter == b
```

should be

```
letter == "a"
```

and

```
letter == "b"
```